I compressed a folder with photos using mac zip and it actually increased in size. Why is that?
Problem - I compressed a folder with photos which was originally 196.7 MB using zip functionality on mac.
The size of the resultant folder is now 202.4 MB. Why is that?
Result - I was expecting it to reduce size.

fdsajhfjkdshfjhdsjkfhdskjhfjkdshfjkdshfjkdshfjksdhfkjhsdfjkhsdjkfhdsjkfhdskjhfjkdshfjkdshfkjdshfkjdshfkjhdsjkfhdsjkfhdsjkhfjkdshfjkdshfjkdshfjkdshfjkhdsjkfhdsjkfhjdksfhjdksfhdskjfhks

Photos are generally already compressed. JPEG files certainly are. Compressed files don't behave well when you try to compress them again, and can end up larger in size. See this question on [su]
